# How to enable "Tracing" in Isabelle/jEdit

Tags: isabelle

I'm a *vim* fan, but only *emacs* has this Isabelle/HOL environment. *jEdit* is great, but I cannot use

```
using [[simp_trace=true]]
```

like in *emacs*.

How to enable "Tracing" in *jEdit*?

Comment: Are you just referring to tracing the simplifier, or other tracing as well?

Comment: Are you using the official Isabelle/jEdit that comes with the Isabelle2013 release?

Comment: Btw: For everything besides Isabelle, I'm also using vim and once upon a time I felt that I had to use Isabelle from inside vim (especially since the only alternative was emacs). At that time a student of mine implemented a vim plugin (long deprecated) that allowed to interact with Isabelle. But this was far inferior to Proof General and would never have been the same smooth experience as interacting with Isabelle through the document model underlying Isabelle/jEdit. So I long gave up on that urge ;)

Comment: Chris is right.  You should not put Isabelle/jEdit into the category with plain text editors.  This is why we position it as "Prover IDE".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can indeed use `simp_trace` in the middle of a proof in Isabelle/jEdit, like so:

```
lemma "(2 :: nat) + 2 = 4"
  using [[simp_trace]]
  apply simp
  done
```

Alternatively, you can declare it globally, like so:

```
declare [[simp_trace]]

lemma "(2 :: nat) + 2 = 4"
  apply simp
  done
```

Both give you the simplifier's trace in the "Output" window when your cursor is just after the `apply simp` statement in jEdit.

Answer (score 7):

If you need a trace depth deeper than 1 (default), you fine-tune it by

```
declare [[simp_trace_depth_limit=4]]
```

This example then gives a trace depth of 4.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, you can use *simp_trace*. However, you can also use *simp_trace_new* combined with the "Simplifier Trace" window. This provides improved output over *simp_trace*:

```
lemma "rev (rev xs) = xs"
  using [[simp_trace_new]]
  apply(induction xs)
  apply(auto)
  done
```

To view the trace, position the cursor over "apply(auto)" then click on "See simplifier trace". The "Simplifier Trace" window(tab) should open. Click on "Show Trace" and a new window should appear showing a trace for each subgoal.

The Isabelle/Isar [reference](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2014/doc/isar-ref.pdf) provides more details:

> *simp_trace_new* controls Simplifier tracing within Isabelle/PIDE applications, notably Isabelle/jEdit. 
>   This provides a hierarchical representation of the rewriting steps performed by the Simplifier.
>   Users can configure the behaviour by specifying breakpoints, verbosity
>   and enabling or disabling the interactive mode.
>   **In normal verbosity (the default), only rule applications matching a breakpoint will be
>   shown to the user**. In full verbosity, all rule applications will be logged.
>   Interactive mode interrupts the normal flow of the Simplifier and defers
>   the decision how to continue to the user via some GUI dialog.

Alternatively you can specify "using [[simp_trace_new mode=full]]" [link here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.science.mathematics.logic.isabelle.user/10125)
To see all steps taken by the simplifier.

NOTE: in the previous example, showing the trace of "apply(induction xs)" yields no output.